# How to pass Automated Workflows from a Smartsheet Template to created Smartsheets using smartsheet-csharp-sdk?

Tags: c#, smartsheet-api, smartsheet-c#-sdk-v2

So, when creating a new Smartsheet from a Template that has Automated Workflows there are some options that must be selected for the Smartsheet to inherit that automation.

[(Example in Smartsheet)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4DDT.png)

The Smartsheet API has built in Inclusion Parameters (Rules and RuleRecipients) that can be passed into a request to serve the same function as what we see in the form above.

**INCLUSION PARAMETERS AVAILABLE IN THE SMARTSHEET API**

Parameters include (optional) -- comma-separated list of elements to copy from the template or sheet:

- attachments
- cellLinks
- data
- discussions
- forms
- rules
- ruleRecipients

The smartsheet-csharp-sdk(v2.126.0) we are using to create the API calls has baked in Inclusion classes with preset parameters. Unfortunately, these Inclusion classes do not contain the Rules and RuleRecipients parameters.

**INCLUSION PARAMETERS IN SDK (Relevant ones)**

```
// Summary:
//     Represents specific elements that can be copied from a Template or Sheet into
//     a new Sheet.
public enum TemplateInclusion
{
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Includes the data.
    DATA = 0,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Includes the attachments.
    ATTACHMENTS = 1,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Includes the discussions.
    DISCUSSIONS = 2,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Includes the cell links.
    CELL_LINKS = 3,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Includes the forms.
    FORMS = 4
}
```

---

```
// Summary:
//     Represents specific elements to include in a response.
public enum SheetLevelInclusion
{
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Includes sheet-level and row-level attachments.
    ATTACHMENTS = 0,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Includes columnType attribute in the row’s cells indicating the type of the column
    //     the cell resides in.
    COLUMN_TYPE = 1,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     contact references
    CONTACT_REFERENCES = 2,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     cross sheet references
    CROSS_SHEET_REFERENCES = 3,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Includes sheet-level and row-level discussions.
    DISCUSSIONS = 4,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Includes column filters and row.filteredOut attribute.
    FILTERS = 5,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Includes column filter definitions
    FILTER_DEFINITIONS = 6,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Includes column, row, and cell formatting.
    FORMAT = 7,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     object representation of cell value
    OBJECT_VALUE = 8,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Includes the owner’s email address and user Id for each sheet.
    OWNER_INFO = 9,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Includes a permalink attribute for each row. A row permalink represents a direct
    //     link to the row in the Smartsheet application.
    ROW_PERMALINK = 10,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     (DEPRECATED: use WRITER_INFO) Includes createdBy and modifiedBy attributes on
    //     the row, indicating the row’s creator and last modifier.
    ROW_WRITER_INFO = 11,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Includes the source object indicating which sheet or template the sheet was created
    //     from, if any.
    SOURCE = 12,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Includes SheetSummary object.
    SUMMARY = 13,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Includes createdBy and modifiedBy attributes on the row or summary fields, indicating
    //     the row or summary field's creator, and last modifier.
    WRITER_INFO = 14
}
```

The CreateSheetFromTemplate method that we are using from the SDK does have an "includes" parameter but it only accepts an IEnumerable of the pre-built TemplateInclusion.

```
Sheet CreateSheetFromTemplate(long workspaceId, Sheet sheet, IEnumerable<TemplateInclusion> includes);
```

I am not sure how to bypass this to add the Rules and RuleRecipients parameters in a way that would work with the SDK. Is it possible to create a Smartsheet that will inherit the Automated Workflows from a Template using the SDK? Or should I just bypass it altogether and create a traditional API call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the source code of the package (https://github.com/smartsheet-platform/smartsheet-csharp-sdk) and the TemplateInclusion never included once rules or ruleRecipients.
I tried to force the call using rest api and rules are supported, but i doubt that rulesRecipents are...

```
url : https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets?include=rules,rulesrecipients,recipients
body : {"name":"newsheetFromTemplate", "fromId": 9999999999}
```

To conclude i would advise:

- Create a feature enhancement request
- Report the issue on github
- Not to use templates but sheet copy (where rules are supported)

Comment: I didn't even consider using the Sheet Copy method. Seems to work like a charm. Appreciate the advice!